# jQuery inside View in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 solutions in ASP.Net MVC.
In both solutions I use jQuery (library included in main layout)
But in latter solution jQuery didnt work in a view.
So I used the @section Scripts { ... } for my jQuery in the View and it worked.
My question is : Why in one solution jQuery worked well without @section Scripts
and why the other solution needed to put my jQuery inside  @section Scripts { ... } in order to work.

Both Views in the solutions have the libraries included in main layout
(by default by Visual Studio)

Code I used:

This isi the test code I used

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnTest').click(function () {
                $('#txtTest').val('Hey');
            });
        });
```

Comment: are you sure that the same version of jquery is used in both solutions and that you were using the same methods. For example in jquery.slim there is no $ajax(). It's hard to say more if you don't show us the error or the code

Comment: It depends, do they have the same layout? Do you have RenderSection scripts on your layout?

Comment: Can you define "worked" and "didn't work"?  Can you provide a minimal but complete example?

Comment: By didn't work I mean browser didn't recognize the $ symbol of jQuery

Comment: @PaulZ.: In that case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined  Aside from that we'd need an actual example of the code.  Showing us how you're trying to use `$` doesn't tell us anything about where you defined `$`.

Answer (score 4):

If jQuery is rendered at the bottom of `_Layout.cshtml`, then you need to place your script inside `@section Scripts`.

By doing so, your script render after jQuery script.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {   
             // Some code         
        })
    </script>
}
```

Sometime, server-side wrapper controls like Kendo UI requires jQuery script renders before its controls. For that case, you simply move jQuery script inside `head` tag.

Comment: Yes it was rendered at the bottom. Thanks

Comment: You just move jQuery script inside `head` tag in `_Layout.cshtml`. If you use bundling, then you can reference [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) and [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice different versions of jQuery in the layouts.

In the solution that doesn't need @section Scripts has jQuery 2.2.4
The solution that does need @section Scripts has jQuery 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add your code in a .js file and then in the bundles so that is available in your application.